# Percentage of a chemical

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My study group is practicing drawing simulated blood for nursing school.

We are first instructed to add $.1\,\rm mL$ of chemical (anticoagulant) to our syringe, then draw enough blood so that the $.1$ does not exceed a $5\%$ concentration of the blood.

How much simulated blood do we draw, so that the addition of $.1\,\rm mL$ of chemical does not dilute the blood more than $5\%$? I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we want your anticoagulant to equal *exactly* 5% concentration in the syringe. Then we have
$$0.1= 0.05V, \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad V = B+0.1$$
Where $V$ is the total volume in the syringe, and $B$ is the volume of the blood we take, to make up a total volume of $V$.

Can you solve these equations? And is this the maximum or the minimum amount of blood you should take?

**Answer rollovers** (though I'd suggest working through it!):

> You should take 1.9mL to give *exactly* 5% concentration.

Second Part:

> The more blood you take, the less concentrated it'll be. So take *at least* 1.9mL.